# Impose the color for one discrete value above a color predefined gradient

Tags: plotting, color

If I plot an array with option `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"`:

```
a = {{0, 1, 5, 3, 0.5, 0, 0, 2, 12, 0.50, 3, 7, 2, 0.2}};
ArrayPlot[a, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: array plot]

but want the points with value = 0 (and only points with value = 0) to appear white (they are missing values) instead of purple, how should I do that? Can I specify a color for discrete points to override what `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"` does?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding the option

```
ColorRules -> {0 -> White}
```

to ArrayPlot works.

Sorry I find the answer 1 min after I ask the question...

Comment: Answering your own question is completely acceptable as long as the question and answer will be helpful for others in future. In this case, I didn't know the answer, so well done, +1.

Answer (score 8):

Not all plot functions accept `ColorRules`, so it is good to know how to construct a custom color function anyway.  For this example:

```
cf = If[# == 0, White, "Rainbow" ~Blend~ #] &;

ArrayPlot[a, ColorFunction -> cf]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More specified colors can be applied with `Piecewise`.  Custom color functions can also apply to multiple dimensions:

```
cf = Piecewise[{
     {Green, 0.2 < #2 < 0.3},
     {Cyan, 0.7 < #2 < 0.8},
     {Yellow, 0.2 < #1 < 0.3},
     {Black, 0.7 < #1 < 0.8}
     }, Blend["Rainbow", #]] &;

Plot[TriangleWave[x], {x, 0, 5},
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], ColorFunction -> cf, PlotPoints -> 5000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You should also see `MeshFunctions`, `MeshStyle`, etc. for such things, which would not require such an extreme `PlotPoints` value, but I wished to make a point.

Answer (score 2):

One could also use `Lighter[]` for the purpose:

```
ArrayPlot[a, ColorFunction -> (Lighter[ColorData["Rainbow", #], Boole[# == 0]] &)]
```

[image: array plot with modified coloring]

Comment: Since `If[# == 0, White, "Rainbow" ~Blend~ #] &` is shorter, is there a reason to prefer this?

Comment: My impetus was that the `Blend["Rainbow", x]` construction might be unfamiliar to most. You and I know this construction, but there is no explicit mention of this thing in the docs.

Comment: Hm... I never noticed that.  +1 for documented functions!

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayPlot[a /. 0 -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]